# Nodejs file exist

Tags: node.js

If i try check exist just one file (whom actualy exists), my test passing 
successfully. But if i try add in asserts non-existing file, both test passed with error

```
    describe('script entry points', function () {
           entryJs = {
             "app": "./coffee/app",
             "shame": "./coffee/shame"
           };

        for(var pointJs in entryJs) { 
           pathJs = 'web/js'+pointJs+'.js';
           it('should return true when '+pathJs+' file exist', function () {
             fs.stat(pathJs, function(err, data) {
               if (err) 
                 console.log('it does not exist');
               else 
                console.log('it exists');
             });
         });
      }
   });
```

Comment: Also i try try{
     fs.statSync(pathJs);
     console.log('it exists');
    } catch(e){
     console.log('it does not exist');
    }

Comment: fs.stat requires absolute path, append __dirname

Comment: your files are
web/jsapp.js and
web/jsshame.js, sure you are checking for these files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `console.log(pathJs);` just before `fs.stat` and you'll find out that `fs.stat` is called twice with same `pathJs` value.

By the time the fs.stat gets called first time the pathJs variable holds the value assigned to it in last *for loop* cycle.

**The reason is asynchronous nature of node.js.** 
You need to use closure.

Solution:

```
for(var pointJs in entryJs) { 
    pathJs = 'web/js/'+entryJs[pointJs]+'.js';     

    (function(path){
         it('should return true when '+path+' file exist', function () { 

              fs.stat(path, function(err, data) { 
                   if (err) 
                       console.log('it does not exist');           
                   else 
                        console.log('it exists'); 
               }); 
         });
    })(pathJs);
}
```

Comment: Thaks, your asynchronous  solution is great for me!